# How to filter / selectively copy values from one DataGridView to another DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter

I have 2 DataGridViews: **productsDataGridView** and **promotionsDataGridView**.

The first one, **productsDataGridView**, which reads **ALL** values from a **file** with this method:

```
public static List<Products> LoadUserListFromFile(string filePath)
{
    var loadProductsData = new List<Products>();

    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
    {
        var columns = line.Split('\t');
        loadProductsData.Add(new Products
        {
            InventoryID = "BG" + columns[0],
            Brand = columns[1],
            Category = columns[2],
            Description = columns[3],
            Promotions = Convert.ToInt32(columns[4]),
            Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(columns[5]),
            Price = Convert.ToDouble(columns[6])
        });
    }

    return loadProductsData;
}
```

The first DataGridView (**productsDataGridView**) is filled correctly with ALL the values. Now in my **productsDataGridView** I have set-up a **check-box** column called "Promotion" (column Promotion reads integer values from the file): if it has value of 0 - the box is not checked, if greater than 1: is checked. 
Now what I WANT to do is to **FILTER/MOVE** (I don't care which of both exactly) the values from **productsDataGridView** to **promotionsDataGridView** where we have a >0 value in the check-box column (promotions).

[image]

**Example:**
If productsDataGridView has 25 total products, from which 8 are promotional products (have value >0 in the check-box column), promotionsDataGridView should be filled with 8 values, which are copied/moved/filtered/whatever from DataGridView.

So far I can only copy the data from the first DataGridView to the second one with the following code:

```
public void Experimental2()
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Products.LoadUserListFromFile(filePath);
    //Bind datagridview to linq 
    var dg1 =
        (from a in productsDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
         select new { Column1 = a.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString() }).ToList();

    //loop dg1 and save it to datagridview2
    foreach (var b in dg1)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(b.Column1);
    }
}
```

I made few pitiful attempts to insert an IF check, which would do the job for me (copy only IF columnt[4] > 0) but I am really new to DataGridView so I just couldn't write anything which  would even compile at all...

Please, help me!

Comment: Have you tried to explore events?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events.aspx
There are many events which can be exploited and can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both grids have same schema (and I assume they have) then we are going to find which rows are checked, get product bound to given row, create new result list and bind it to the next grid.

```
var results = new List<Products>(); //our new data source with only checked items

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in productsDataGridView.Rows)
{
    var item = row.DataBoundItem as Products; //get product from row (only when grid is databound!)

    if (item.Promotions > 0)
    {
        results.Add(item);        
    }
}

promotionsDataGridView.DataSource = results;
```

If you want to delete rows from first grid that are checked then create temporary list of rows, add to it checked rows and at the end iterate over them and remove one by one. Hope that help You out :)

Comment: By the way: The two DGV are NOT exactly the same. I select only 5 columns from the first one.

Comment: Edited, there was mistake, forgot to add `.Rows` :). Also grids do not have to be the same only thiers columns should have identical databindings set

Comment: I did not test it but I used all the info you gave (and some assumptions :)). Still it should work just fine. Changed some code, please try it.

Comment: Yes, it works, lol, imagine how stupid I am... I DID NOT LOAD THE METHOD IN FORM_LOAD!... :D Much love from me! <3 <3 <3