# How I can update a datagridview for child Form from another datagridview in a parent Form

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, datagridview

I have DataGridView(dgHome) has some columns in parentForm(Home).
And A child Form(bill) have DataGridView(dgbill) .
I need When I click any columns in dgHome then it add this columns to dgbill.
I hope it's clear.

```
    `private void dgMenu_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

{
        DataTable dt;
        if (e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            if (k < 4)
            {
                DataGridViewRow rw = this.dgMenu.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                string t = rw.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                if (k == 1)
                {
                    dt = f.SelectFoodType(t);
                }
                else if (k == 2)
                {
                    dt = a.SelectAdditionType(t);
                }
                else if (k == 3)
                {
                    dt = d.SelectDrinkType(t);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("select Food, Drink or Addition");
                    return;
                }
                dgMenu.DataSource = null;
                dgMenu.DataSource = dt;
                dgMenu.Columns[0].Visible = dgMenu.Columns[2].Visible = false;
                dgMenu.Columns[1].HeaderText = t;
                dgMenu.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Price";
                k = 100;
            }
            else
            {
                DataGridViewRow rw = this.dgMenu.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                string productname = rw.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                string price = rw.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                string input = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter Quantity: ", "Quantity", "1", -1, -1);
                int q;
                bool x = int.TryParse(input, out q);
                if (x)
                {
                    EnBill b = new EnBill(UserId);
                    if (IsFormOpen(typeof(EnBill)))
                    {
                        /* in this space I want to add this columns to another DataGridView in another Form*/
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No Input or Valid Input");
                }
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Show what did you tried and where you stack?

Comment: Hm...show us some love...post some code, and say where or what doesn't work for u.

Comment: sorry I can't post any Image and my code is complex

Comment: Finally I add a code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Row.DataBoundItem` to get the data bound to the row. This data could be then set to the DataGridView in child form. There is a similar question which is already answered.

[How to filter / selectively copy values from one DataGridView to another DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643908/how-to-filter-selectively-copy-values-from-one-datagridview-to-another-datagri)

Added working code...

```
public class Customer
{
    string name;
    int age;

    public Customer(string thename, int theage)
    {
        name = thename;
        age = theage;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

}
public class ChildForm : Form
{
    DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
    public ChildForm()
    {
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
        dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    public void AddData(List<Customer> theData)
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = theData;
    }
}
public class ParentForm : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new ParentForm());
    }


    DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
    Button button1 = new Button();
    ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();

    public ParentForm()
    {
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
        this.Controls.Add(button1);
        this.Load += new EventHandler(ParentForm_Load);
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        button1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        button1.Text = "CopyToChild";
        dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            Customer customer = row.DataBoundItem as Customer;
            if (customer != null)
            {
                customers.Add(customer);
            }
        }
        childForm.AddData(customers);

    }

    private void ParentForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        System.Collections.ArrayList customers = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

        customers.Add(new Customer("Thor", 120));
        customers.Add(new Customer("Loki", 110));
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = customers;
        childForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the way to how use DataGridView of child in Parent Form

Comment: Expose a method in child form which would take the data from the parent DataGridView as parameter and fill the DataGridView within this method. I wouldn't suggest to access the control directly. But still if you want to access make the DataGridView control public.